# How can I get an older version of .NET Standard?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md), targeting the .NET Standard Platform 1.3 allow my library to be used within a 4.6 .NET program.

Am I right about that ?

If I am, my problem is, I can't find a way to downgrade my .net core Library (except for the 1.5.0-rc2)

(Excuse me for my English, I am not a native speaker)

Comment: in nuget, download `netstandard1.3`

Comment: it was my first thought too, but as I said, there is only the 1.5.0-rc2 version available on [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NETStandard.Library/1.6.0) (and 1.6 of course).

Comment: the documentation is pretty clear that if you download `netstandard1.6` you can target a previous version like `netstandard1.3`.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tutorials/libraries  " You control the range of targetable platforms and versions by picking a version of netstandardX.X (Where X.X is a version number) and adding it to your project.json file."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project.json you could defined more than one target framework. Each target can have custom dependency package and/or common dependencies.

```
{
  ...
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {  },
    "NET46: { },
    "NET40: { },
    "NET35: { },
}
```

Comment: I tried this with some progress but I am still stuck ... I have 4 projects : 1 .net core library with "frameworks": { "netstandard1.3": { } } in project.json, 1 console in 4.5 .NET, 1 console in 4.6 .NET and 1 console in .NET Core. I can't add the library in the 4.5 project (not compatible with .net standard 1.3, I agree with that) and I can add it in the two others project. But the classes of my Library are not visibile within the 4.6 project (where they are visible in the .net core project)

Comment: I'm not sure but I think this is not supported. You could at least run `dotnet pack` on your .net core project and then use the generated nupkg in other project.

Comment: Sorry, I take my time to answer. You were right, it is not possible to add a xproject library as a direct reference into a classic csproj library. But by packaging it and adding it through the nuget way, it works like a charm :D !